# UIWebView: How to insert text in a HTML text field

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I've an *UIWebView* where a mobile web form URL is loaded. In a method in my application, I would like to insert some text into the HTML text field in the UIWebView which has focus.

How can I do that? Is there a way to get the ID of the HTML element which has focus -- than I can insert the text into this element using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out being a JavaScript question, as my solution was to use the jQuery call `$("*:focus")` to change the value of the selected element in the *UIWebView*. This obviously requires that the page loaded in the *UIWebView* is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). The call was made using `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` as *Sixten Otto* describes.

Answer (score 2):

The sole way you have to affect the page loaded into the `UIWebView` is [`-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a). The least troublesome way would probably be to set up a function in your page that you can call with the text you want in the field. Then pass in a string that is the call to that function, like:

```
 NSString* js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunction('%@')", someTextVariable];
 NSString* results = [self.someWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

(Escaping any single quotes in `someTextVariable` would also be necessary!)