# Launch website and log in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, ipad

I'm writing ios app. In my app user input login and password to his facebook account. Is it possible to launch [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com) and, using this login and password, automatically sign in?

This question seems to have been asked but without enough results for me.

Comment: Most certainly: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Comment: i don't want to use someone's profile in my app, only "click - launch safari - open website.com - automatically sign in "

Comment: "This question seems to have been asked but without enough results for me." What are these questions that you have looked at. We could just be sending you back to them. Please include what you have looked at in your question.

Comment: There is a lot questions... I'm not new at stack overflow and, for this my question, i many hours explored stackoverflow, many other sites and a lot of documentations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like OAuth:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Comment: I don't need to ask user to log in. I have saved user's data and want to use it.

Comment: Am I right in the assumption that you somehow obtain the users Facebook Name and password and then want to sign in using these credentials? Form a security point of view this is horrible..

Comment: i'm writting something like 1Password, so yes, i will have user's data, and with security everything is ok :)

Comment: Well you would probably solve this using JavaScript:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565320/uiwebview-how-to-insert-text-in-a-html-text-field